# Store data from URL in Joomla website database

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, plugin, database, url

I just came through a scenario regarding joomla website.

The scenario is:

Data in URL is passed to Joomla website and from the URL Joomla must store the data into the database.

Is this possible in Joomla?

Comment: provide a sample of url in your question for better understanding

Comment: Of course it is, but it will require some custom code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: the redirect plugin already does that... depending on your requirements it could do

Comment: Please progress this old question toward a resolution. This question risks being Too Broad, but if you narrow it down and add some context as well as what you tried, then those that wish to volunteer their support can write something direct and clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value of a URL parameter with:

```
$value = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('parameter');
```

Then you can use `JDatabaseQuery` to insert data into the database.

- **https://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase**
- **https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput**

Answer (score 1):

You will need to develop a system plugin for that. The system plugin will grab the URL, parses the data that you need, and then store it in a table of your choice.